# Trace.Trace*** doesn't write to Azure Application Log in File System

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an web site hosted on Azure. I am trying to log things that happen on the server.

Under "application diagnostics", I set `APPLICATION LOGGING (FILE SYSTEM)` to `ON`.
I don't have any storage accounts and therefore cannot use `(TABLE STORAGE)` or `(BLOB STORAGE)`.

Here is an example of the code I use to write to the log:

```
Trace.TraceInformation("This is a test message");
```

Files gets created in `[mySite]/Log Files/Application` but they only have two lines in them:

```
2014-11-05T09:17:30  PID[redacted] Information DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[redacted] (official)
2014-11-05T09:17:30  PID[redacted] Information Reporting will use isolated storage with scope: Domain, Assembly, Machine
```

Are there other settings that I need to set?
Are there actions I need to perform before attempting to write to the log?